# Oracle APEX: Bar chart with multiple series

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, bar-chart, oracle-apex

I have problem with Bar chart (with multiple series) in Oracle Apex. For example i have created simple bar chart with two series (April, December) from emp table.

[image]

Source for series is SQL query.

**For April:**

```
select job, count(job) as "Number of employees" from emp where to_char(HIREDATE, 'MON') = 'APR' GROUP BY job
```

**For December:**

```
select job, count(job) as "Number of employees" from emp where to_char(HIREDATE, 'MON') = 'DEC' GROUP BY job
```

Problem is that generated chart is not correct:

[image]

For Clerk there are no values in chart but there must be two emp. for December.
This is output of mentioned queries from sql developer:

**For April:**

[image]

**For December:**

[image]

There is no problem when i use only one serie, problem is only with multiple series. I use Apex 5.1 with Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my question. It is bug which is fixed in apex version 5.1.3 .